# How to get value of specified part of pattern from URL string like MVC route using php?

Tags: php, regex, string, url, replace

i have these variables:

```
$pathPattern = '/catalog/{name}/{id}';
$pathRealUrl = '/catalog/test-product/12343';
```

The `$pathPattern` is dynamic, from a json file.
The `$pathRealUrl` is the url.

Now I need to create this two variables:

```
$name = 'test-product';
$id = 12343;
```

Note that the `$pathPattern` can have many variables
and also that `{name}` and `{id}` can have different name ( like `{xxx}` or `{pippo}` ), other sample:

```
$pathPattern = '/home/test/{hello}';
$pathRealUrl = '/home/test/alex';
```

The best way for archive this?

Comment: you can use str_replace function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split both string by `/` delimiter and loop through generated array from `$pathPattern`. In loop, get string that is between `{` and `}` and create variable named to it. At the end, set value of relevant index of `$pathRealUrlArr` in created variable.

```
$pathPatternArr = explode("/", $pathPattern);
$pathRealUrlArr = explode("/", $pathRealUrl);
foreach($pathPatternArr as $key=>$item){
    if (preg_match("/^{(\w+)}$/", $item, $matches))
        ${$matches[1]} = $pathRealUrlArr[$key];      
}
echo $name, $id;
```

See result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/cp8Tt)

You can shorten the code like bottom

```
foreach(explode("/", $pathPattern) as $key=>$item){
    if (preg_match("/^{(\w+)}$/", $item, $matches))
        ${$matches[1]} = explode("/", $pathRealUrl)[$key];      
}
echo $name, $id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$pathPattern = '/catalog/{name}/{id}';
$pathRealUrl = '/catalog/test-product/12343';
$b = explode("/", $pathPattern);
$e = explode("/", $pathRealUrl);
$i = 0;
foreach ($b as $v) {
    ${substr($v,1,-1)} = $e[$i];     
    $i++;
}
echo $name;
echo $id;
```

And:

```
$i = 0;
foreach (explode("/", $pathPattern) as $v) {
    ${substr($v,1,-1)} = explode("/", $pathRealUrl)[$i];     
    $i++;
}
```

[Show demo](https://3v4l.org/bGB9v)

Comment: Ok, but the $name variable is dynamic, could be $pippo or $hello, based on  $pathPattern

Answer (score 0):

If the count of the number of values between the slashes will remain same or the position of the `{name}/{id}` will remain same then you can use `explode` to split the string by "/" and the get the desired values from the resultant array.
e.g.

```
$pathRealUrl = '/catalog/test-product/12343';
$array = explode("/",$pathRealUrl );
$id = $array[count($array)-1];
$name = $array[count($array)-2];
```

Ideone link : http://ideone.com/aNpxEJ

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: No, the count of the number of values will be not the same

Comment: @Ste What about the position of id and name ?? Will they remain at the end??